# The equation $a^2 - 4b = 3$ has no integer solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

> Prove that: $$a^2 - 4b \neq 3$$ for all integers $a$ and $b$.

I'm not sure how to find a way to prove this statement. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried?  What must be true for a and b such that the statement is true?   Try finding a contradiction.

Comment: Hint: Consider the possibilities for $a\pmod 4$.

Comment: You could use a graph

Comment: @ajax333221: $a^2$ is not always even. Eg:$9$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that it is true. So $a^2-4b=3$.

Case I :When $a$ is even. Then $a=2k$ where $k$ is an integer. Thus we have, $4(k^2-b)=3$. LHS is even and RHS is odd. Contradiction.

CaseII: When $a$ is odd. Then $a=2k+1$ where $k$ is an integer. Then, $(2k+1)^2-4b=3$, hence we have $2(k^2+k-b)=1$. Again LHS even, RHS odd. Contradiction.

Comment: $a$ cannot be even. $a^2$ is 3+4b which is always odd, and if $a^2$ is odd, then a must be as well.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\mod4$

LHS $\equiv 0,1 \pmod 4$ but RHS $\equiv 3$

So no solutions